# native libraries configuration under tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jmagick

I am trying to get the JMagick library working under Tomcat to do some image
translation following an upload.

Magic comes as a semi-stub library.jar archive and a native library
libJMagick.so . I have used
      `System. LoadLibrary ("JMagick");`,
but I get errors in the `catalina.out` complaining about being unable to find
the library (details at the end of this message). the key clause being:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load MagickLoader (class not found) at magick.Magick.(Magick.java:25)

So where should I put the libraries, currently they are in WEB-INF/lib so that tomcat can use them

Comment: They need to be added to your classpath. Use this to see how it looks:

Comment: @Stefoan- can you post the link to which you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If your shared object is not installed througha package manager, put into `setenv.sh` `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CATALINA_BASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and copy the so to that lib directory.

Comment: I copied .so files to my tomcat's lib folder and added LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CATALINA_BASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH to catalina.sh as I dont have setenv.sh .Its not working for me. Same error I am getting

Comment: Do not modify the `catalina.sh`. Always put stuff in `setenv.sh`. If that file does not exist, create it in `bin` and add
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: setenv.sh 9504 2012-12-10 16:19:19Z osipovmi $
umask 022

LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I created setenv.sh in bin with content  #!/bin/sh 
# $Id: setenv.sh 9504 2012-12-10 16:19:19Z osipovmi 
$ umask 022
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/lib:/opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" export LD_LIBRARY_PATH where /opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib is path where my .so files are.Still getting same error.

Comment: Please remove the trailing `/` and show how the exact so name is.

Comment: which trailing / are you talking about?

Comment: My .so file is in /opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib/ directory.So you want me to write full path like /opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib/jmagick.so?

Comment: actually i have 2 .so files So I tried doing   $ umask 022
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/lib:/opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib/libJMagick.so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/lib:/opt/jmagick-6.4.0/lib/libJMagick-6.4.0.so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"  Still getting same error
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Did you set the `x` bit?

Comment: Which x bit are you talking about?

Comment: The mod of the so must look like this `r-xr-xr-x`. Otherwise the lib is not loadable.

Comment: permissions are fine they are rwxrwxrwx

Comment: OK, seems fine. I would write a small Java test class which resembles your problem and see whether lib is loaded or not. I'd like to exclude any config-related problems.

Comment: Did you get a chance to write that java Test class?

Comment: @user2523002, that task has directed to you. That's why I wrote: "I would write" and not "I will write one for you".